# Plug-In's Selection Not Accessible

Tags: plugins

My site has had some issues in updating most meta descriptions & page titles (actually, issues updating *any* description or title). While chasing a rabbit hole, I realized I don't have WordPress set up correctly to trouble shoot correctly using the help of these forums because I can't access the Yoast plugin because I can't access any plugins at all.

Is this a problem with my access level or how WP is operating?
I'm using WP 5.0.3

This is what my nav menu looks like:

[image]

Comment: are you an admin?

Comment: Keep in mind these aren't discussion forums, this is a Q&A site. You need to be able to ask a specific question, then mark an answer that's correct for everyone, not just for you. Looking at your screenshot you do have plugins listed there, but i'd bear in mind that Yoast and other 3rd party plugin support is offtopic here, you should go to their support forums